# How to compress a string of 0s and 1s in java

Tags: java, binary, compression, huffman-code

I am doing Huffman Coding right now and I ran into this bump in the road. I have pretty much everything done but this one part. My main issue right now is I am not sure how to store my binary string of 0s and 1s that is encoded using my code. I try just writing it out normally but the file size of that ends up being much bigger then the original text file that I encoded. Can someone give me any ideas of how I should store my binary strings so that this don't happen.

Update
I have notice that a lot of char is not recognized when I try to cast it to a char and ends up being printed out as ?s and when I do

```
String u = scanner.nextLine();
    char l;
    for(int b = 0;b<u.length();b++)
    {
    l = u.charAt(b);
    int c = (int) u.charAt(b);
    String p = Integer.toBinaryString(c);

    if(b!= u.length()-1)
    {
    while(p.length()!=8){
        p = "0" + p;
    //Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    }System.out.println(p);
    k.append(p);
```

it reads in the ? and print out 00111111. Anyone has any suggestions of how I can fix this?

Comment: Why not store the 0 and 1's as 0 and 1's in binary instead of text?  If you want to compress these further you could use the built in compression which also uses huffman encoding as well as arithmetic coding

Answer (score 2):

When you are storing the binary string it is just that, a `String`. One way of storing them more efficiently is converting the binary string to integers and using these to store the string as ASCII characters.

1. Cut the string into short pieces of 8 characters each (1 byte = 8 bits)
2. Use `Integer.parseInt(piece, 2);` to convert the binary piece into an `int`
3. Now cast the integer to a `char`
4. Repeat this for every piece of the binary string.

You then join up the `chars` into a string and store the result as a plain text file. This should result in file that is 8x smaller than your previous binary string file.

[EDIT]
This is working en and decoding code that has been tested under a variety of circumstances.
http://pastebin.com/Tq3nKX8A
Please use it as you see fit.

Comment: Will the out put of this still be the same string?

Comment: The output will not be the same string, it will be a String of ASCII characters that can easily be decoded by following the instructions in reverse. ie, cast the char to int, convert the int binary and string together the 0's and 1's. You can use that with your Huffman decoding algorithm.

Comment: i dont want to be asking for to much but is there any way you can provide a sample code. If you have the time that is.

Comment: I have produced some example code for the binary -> String conversion here: [PasteBin Link](http://pastebin.com/KEYV8jgx) You should be able to reverse the process on your own. ( It's very similar, except you should use `Integer.toBinaryString(n)` to convert the int to binary.

Comment: I am not sure how to cast the character back to integers.

Comment: A simple cast with `(int)'c'` would do the trick. I have compiled example code (again, untested) to help you on your way here: http://pastebin.com/LNseX9bP . You should be set up and ready to go if this works :)

Comment: Dude I cannot express how much I appreciate you help. I am going to test this out.

Comment: i found out your way is actually the same idea I used, but for some reason when I try to change from character back to integer the binary string is not the same.

Comment: Checked this out again, only thing I can think of is the following: Using `Integer.toBinaryString(n)` will result in a String with the minimum amount of characters. ie 29 -> 11101 instead of the 8 characters you expect (00011101). Be sure to pad every number out to 8 characters with 0 before turning them into `char`s.  http://pastebin.com/KEYV8jgx contains some padding code from line 19 to 22. This will make sure that the original bits are retained, instead of being neglected by the int->String conversion.

Comment: I did that all my string are coming out at size 8 but when i decode it some of the characters when transfer back into binary string gives me a binary string that is not 8 characters long.

Comment: But there is some that is exactly the same.

Comment: Okay dude I found the problem that fixed majority of my code by i have one last problem is how to get the remaining binary string cause in my code i get left over with 0111 during converting from binary to char but i cant pad this because then it woould be difficult to restore this back since the length of this is undetermined cause it is what ever is left over. When i just convert as is when transfer back i only get the character 111 and i cant necessarily say pad an extra 0 since that might only work for this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have already mentioned this above, as with your previous question. The last characters are padded with 0's. This is possible due to the nature of bit operations; They are read from right to left, and any 0's after the last 1 are effectively ignored. Therefor 00000010 == 10 (=2). You CAN pad the last piece without problems if you do it properly.

Comment: Okay, reread this. It seems we misread eachother somewhat. I think I see your point about the last character being unpredicatable, as a leading 0 will be overlooked in the transfer from binary to int. I neglected to add this to the original answer as it seemed out of the scope of the question. To ensure the right amount of binary characters I would recommend either reserving the first character to store the length of the last piece. That way you can ensure that it is decoded properly. If this still does not solve your problem I suggest we move this to chat, as this thread is quite long.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Sorry for making this so long because I dont have enough rep to go to chat yet. I also ran to another problem why debugging. It seem that some binary string can be changed into the same character and when change back it might not give you back the same string. Ex 00111111 and 10001101 both end up giving u the character "?".

Comment: "?" indicates that the character cannot be displayed in the editor you are using. Some ASCII values (Like 141, see http://www.ascii-code.com/) are not assigned to a character, or cannot be recognized by your editor. They wil still have their integer value, however, and can as such be decoded properly.

Comment: Also, 00111111 = 63, which is just the "?" character ;)

Comment: If the code is 00111111 it decode properly but when I have 10001101 it just decode as if it was 00111111. I must be missing something my code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tq3nKX8A This code has been tested and known to work under all the circumstances you mentioned. It will transform the binary code into an ASCII string and back (with 1 byte of extra information for decoding). If this does not solve your specific problem I'm afraid it has to do with your huffman encoding/decoding code. I suggest you ask a new question with new details to resolve it. I have updated my answer with this code.